# How to parse the query to hours instead of days in usql

Tags: sql-server, u-sql

I need to update logic to add buffer to to do data for last 24 hours instead of 7 days

```
DECLARE @todo = @opinion== 0? DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays( - 7) : new DateTime(@opinion);
```

Tried this with offset but it didn't work for me.

```
DECLARE @todo = @opinion== 0? DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) : new DateTimeOffset(@opinion, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24));
```

Comment: What is @opinion? What should it have? Integer value? Date value?

Comment: its a Date value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opinion is within the last 7 hours

```cssharp
DECLARE @opinion = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-9);

SELECT ...
WHERE opinion >=  DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-7) AND opinion <= DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Missing details for a complete answer.